# Group json string by key and add to array

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, underscore.js, sails.js

I've been at this for a while now and can't seem to get this. I am also relatively new to javascript. My goal is to create an array (or new javascript object) that has the format

```
{
  data:{
    [A1:"first column first row", B1:"second column", C1:"third column",...etc],
    [A2:"first column first row", B2:"second column", C2:"third column",...etc],
    [A3:"first column first row", B3:"second column", C3:"third column",...etc],
    [A4:"first column first row", B4:"second column", C4:"third column",...etc],
    [A5:"first column first row", B5:"second column", C5:"third column",...etc]
    }
}
```

which could be closely related to how excel is formatted with rows and columns. I plan to use this to then feed [handsontable](http://handsontable.com/index.html) for the client side manipulation of this data.

What I currently have is

```
var file = __dirname + '/../../clientFiles/exceltest.json';
fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        sails.log.error('ERROR: ' + err);
        return;
    }
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    var rows = Object.keys(data);
    rows.forEach(function(column) {
        var items = Object.keys(data[column]);
        items.sort();
        items.forEach(function(item) {
            var value = data[column][item];
            console.log(item+' = '+value);
        });
    });
});
```

The key names will never be less than 2 characters, but can grow in size (e.g A1 => AAA1) just like in excel.

The web page script is

```
<div id="dataTable"></div>
<script>
$("#dataTable").handsontable({
    data: <%= data %>,
    startRows: 6,
    startCols: 8,
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: true,
});
</script>
```

the json I am pullng is formatted like

```
{
"sheet1": {
    "F15": "4,385.97",
    "G15": "910.36",
    "H15": "1,555.36",
    "I15": "373.74",
    "J15": "24.03%",
    "K15": "58.53%",
    "L15": "61",
    "M15": "669",
    "N15": "216665",
    "B16": "01/14/2014",
    "D16": "829",
    "E16": "12,997.13",
    "F16": "531.85",
    "G16": "225.48",
    "H16": "359.21",
    "I16": "80.21",
    "J16": "22.33%",
    "K16": "62.77%",
    "L16": "55",
    "M16": "99",
    "N16": "45384",
    "B17": "01/14/2014",
    "D17": "320",
    "E17": "6,142.45",
    "F17": "1,643.42",
    "G17": "129.76",
    "H17": "215.90",
    "I17": "41.09",
    "J17": "19.03%",
    "K17": "60.10%",
    "L17": "111",
    "M17": "182",
    "N17": "35485",
    "D18": "13478",
    "E18": "94,735.05",
    "F18": "6,663.08",
    "G18": "1,689.97",
    "H18": "3,054.92",
    "I18": "839.16",
    "J18": "27.47%",
    "K18": "55.32%",
    "L18": "29",
    "M18": "996",
    "N18": "396396"
},
"sheet2": {
    "F15": "4,385.97",
    "G15": "910.36",
    "H15": "1,555.36",
    "I15": "373.74",
    "J15": "24.03%",
    "K15": "58.53%",
    "L15": "61",
    "M15": "669",
    "N15": "216665",
    "B16": "01/14/2014",
    "D16": "829",
    "E16": "12,997.13",
    "F16": "531.85",
    "G16": "225.48",
    "H16": "359.21",
    "I16": "80.21",
    "J16": "22.33%",
    "K16": "62.77%",
    "L16": "55",
    "M16": "99",
    "N16": "45384",
    "B17": "01/14/2014",
    "D17": "320",
    "E17": "6,142.45",
    "F17": "1,643.42",
    "G17": "129.76",
    "H17": "215.90",
    "I17": "41.09",
    "J17": "19.03%",
    "K17": "60.10%",
    "L17": "111",
    "M17": "182",
    "N17": "35485",
    "D18": "13478",
    "E18": "94,735.05",
    "F18": "6,663.08",
    "G18": "1,689.97",
    "H18": "3,054.92",
    "I18": "839.16",
    "J18": "27.47%",
    "K18": "55.32%",
    "L18": "29",
    "M18": "996",
    "N18": "396396"
  }
}
```

I am using sails and nodejs for my framework and engine. I have been able to sort the keys, but grouping them eludes me. I can make use of underscorejs if need be.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The data structure that you show on the top doesn't make much sense, you define an array like a hash, and then a hash that contains arrays...?

Comment: @htatche is right; the structure you're showing isn't valid JSON.  Also, it's unclear what kind of grouping you're looking for.  The JSON data you pasted at the bottom is divided into sheets, each of which have the same rows and columns, but the structure you specified at the top has one array per row...

Comment: To confirm: you are looking to group the data such that each row is represented by a single array, and the values in that array represent the values from each column in that row? So, you're looking to put all "A*" keys in the same array, all "B*" keys in another array, etc.?

Comment: @htatche - I fixed the json in my original post, I put the wrong character.

Comment: @Kyle - you are correct. I am parsing an excel workbook with xlsjs and have created the above json. The keys are actually excel fields (e.g. column a, row 1). Using handsontable I want to display this json on a page. The issue is that hands on table expects a data format of array ([[a1,b1,c1],[a2,b2,c2]]) and object ([{a1:1},{b1:2},{c1:3}]). Each array [] or object {} seperated by a comma ([], or {},) starts a new line in the handsontable grid.

Comment: @ScottGress - the json I posted is just an example. I can't post the real json as it holds company data, the structure is what matters. The  section at the top of my post is what I would like to create from the json the code is consuming so it works with handsontablejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will code will format your JSON appropriately, but I'm not sure if you wanted all the sheets combined into one.

**Update**: Using the format you provided, the JSON will not work with [handsontable](http://handsontable.com/index.html). I've updated my solution to the correct format and included the integration code for [handsontable](http://handsontable.com/index.html).

**Update 2**: Included column definitions so the table paints correctly.

<kbd>**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9EDMP/3/)**</kbd>

**JS**

```
var sheets = {
"sheet1": {
    "F15": "4,385.97",
    "G15": "910.36",
    "H15": "1,555.36",
    "I15": "373.74",
    "J15": "24.03%",
    "K15": "58.53%",
    "L15": "61",
    "M15": "669",
    "N15": "216665",
    "B16": "01/14/2014",
    "D16": "829",
    "E16": "12,997.13",
    "F16": "531.85",
    "G16": "225.48",
    "H16": "359.21",
    "I16": "80.21",
    "J16": "22.33%",
    "K16": "62.77%",
    "L16": "55",
    "M16": "99",
    "N16": "45384",
    "B17": "01/14/2014",
    "D17": "320",
    "E17": "6,142.45",
    "F17": "1,643.42",
    "G17": "129.76",
    "H17": "215.90",
    "I17": "41.09",
    "J17": "19.03%",
    "K17": "60.10%",
    "L17": "111",
    "M17": "182",
    "N17": "35485",
    "D18": "13478",
    "E18": "94,735.05",
    "F18": "6,663.08",
    "G18": "1,689.97",
    "H18": "3,054.92",
    "I18": "839.16",
    "J18": "27.47%",
    "K18": "55.32%",
    "L18": "29",
    "M18": "996",
    "N18": "396396"
},
"sheet2": {
    "F15": "4,385.97",
    "G15": "910.36",
    "H15": "1,555.36",
    "I15": "373.74",
    "J15": "24.03%",
    "K15": "58.53%",
    "L15": "61",
    "M15": "669",
    "N15": "216665",
    "B16": "01/14/2014",
    "D16": "829",
    "E16": "12,997.13",
    "F16": "531.85",
    "G16": "225.48",
    "H16": "359.21",
    "I16": "80.21",
    "J16": "22.33%",
    "K16": "62.77%",
    "L16": "55",
    "M16": "99",
    "N16": "45384",
    "B17": "01/14/2014",
    "D17": "320",
    "E17": "6,142.45",
    "F17": "1,643.42",
    "G17": "129.76",
    "H17": "215.90",
    "I17": "41.09",
    "J17": "19.03%",
    "K17": "60.10%",
    "L17": "111",
    "M17": "182",
    "N17": "35485",
    "D18": "13478",
    "E18": "94,735.05",
    "F18": "6,663.08",
    "G18": "1,689.97",
    "H18": "3,054.92",
    "I18": "839.16",
    "J18": "27.47%",
    "K18": "55.32%",
    "L18": "29",
    "M18": "996",
    "N18": "396396"
  }
}; 

function processJSON(sheets){
    var data = []; 

    for(var sheet in sheets){
        var curSheet = sheets[sheet];
        var rowData = {}; 
        var curRowNum = -1; 
        var nextRowNum; 
        for(var cell in curSheet){

            nextRowNum = parseInt(cell.replace( /^\D+/g, ''),10); 
            cellLetter = cell.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');
            if(nextRowNum !== curRowNum){
                debugger;
                rowData = {}; 
                data.push(rowData); 
                curRowNum = nextRowNum; 
            }
            rowData[cellLetter] = curSheet[cell];  
        }
    }
    return data; 
}

var data = processJSON(sheets); 

console.log(data); 

$('#example').handsontable({
    data: data,
    minSpareRows:0,
    colHeaders: true,
    contextMenu: true,
    columns: [
        {data: "A"},
        {data: "B"},
        {data: "C"},
        {data: "D"},
        {data: "E"},
        {data: "F"},
        {data: "G"},
        {data: "H"},
        {data: "I"},
        {data: "J"},
        {data: "K"},
        {data: "L"},
        {data: "M"},
        {data: "N"},
        {data: "O"},
        {data: "P"},
        {data: "Q"},
        {data: "R"},
        {data: "S"}
      ]
});


function bindDumpButton() {
    $('body').on('click', 'button[name=dump]', function () {
        var dump = $(this).data('dump');
        var $container = $(dump);
        console.log('data of ' + dump, $container.handsontable('getData'));
    });
}
bindDumpButton();
```

**Results**

```
[
  {
    "F": "4,385.97",
    "G": "910.36",
    "H": "1,555.36",
    "I": "373.74",
    "J": "24.03%",
    "K": "58.53%",
    "L": "61",
    "M": "669",
    "N": "216665"
  },
  {
    "B": "01/14/2014",
    "D": "829",
    "E": "12,997.13",
    "F": "531.85",
    "G": "225.48",
    "H": "359.21",
    "I": "80.21",
    "J": "22.33%",
    "K": "62.77%",
    "L": "55",
    "M": "99",
    "N": "45384"
  },
  {
    "B": "01/14/2014",
    "D": "320",
    "E": "6,142.45",
    "F": "1,643.42",
    "G": "129.76",
    "H": "215.90",
    "I": "41.09",
    "J": "19.03%",
    "K": "60.10%",
    "L": "111",
    "M": "182",
    "N": "35485"
  },
  {
    "D": "13478",
    "E": "94,735.05",
    "F": "6,663.08",
    "G": "1,689.97",
    "H": "3,054.92",
    "I": "839.16",
    "J": "27.47%",
    "K": "55.32%",
    "L": "29",
    "M": "996",
    "N": "396396"
  },
  {
    "F": "4,385.97",
    "G": "910.36",
    "H": "1,555.36",
    "I": "373.74",
    "J": "24.03%",
    "K": "58.53%",
    "L": "61",
    "M": "669",
    "N": "216665"
  },
  {
    "B": "01/14/2014",
    "D": "829",
    "E": "12,997.13",
    "F": "531.85",
    "G": "225.48",
    "H": "359.21",
    "I": "80.21",
    "J": "22.33%",
    "K": "62.77%",
    "L": "55",
    "M": "99",
    "N": "45384"
  },
  {
    "B": "01/14/2014",
    "D": "320",
    "E": "6,142.45",
    "F": "1,643.42",
    "G": "129.76",
    "H": "215.90",
    "I": "41.09",
    "J": "19.03%",
    "K": "60.10%",
    "L": "111",
    "M": "182",
    "N": "35485"
  },
  {
    "D": "13478",
    "E": "94,735.05",
    "F": "6,663.08",
    "G": "1,689.97",
    "H": "3,054.92",
    "I": "839.16",
    "J": "27.47%",
    "K": "55.32%",
    "L": "29",
    "M": "996",
    "N": "396396"
  }
]
```

Comment: thanks for this! I'll look deeper into what you posted in the morning.

Comment: This works really well, thanks for getting me going again from my road block. In response to your question, I was hoping to keep the sheets separate and use their names for pagination in handsontable (so sheet1 a1 and sheet 2 a1 wouldn't cause an issue), but after looking more into it I don't think handsontable supports anything like that yet.

Comment: What I could do is change your loop to pull the sheet name, push the values to the sheet name, making it an array for each "sheet", then push the sheet array to a main array. That would give me "sheet":{sheet keys} to work with. This looks similar to what I started with in my above json, except that duplicate fields ([sheet1, a1] and [sheet2, a1]) wouldn't cause any conflict with each other because they would be rendered in a different window. Thanks again for the help.